# angular push adds operator that that results in MongoError

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, meanjs

I am implementing the tutorial on the mean stack https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AEE7DY2AYvI

I am adding a delete feature to remove items from the database on a button click
[image: Remove first button to remove first item in list from mongodb]

My client side controller has the following 2 functions to add to db and remove

```
$scope.createMeetup = function() {
    var meetup = new Meetup();
    meetup.name = $scope.meetupName;
    meetup.$save(function (result) {
        $scope.meetups.push(result);
        $scope.meetupName = '';
    });
}

$scope.deleteMeetup = function() {
    item = $scope.meetups[0];
    console.log("deleting meetup: " + item["name"]);
    Meetup.delete(item);
    scope.meetups.shift();
}
```

My server side has the following code

```
module.exports.create = function (req, res) {
    var meetup = new Meetup(req.body);
    meetup.save(function (err, result) {
        res.json(result);
    });
}

module.exports.remove = function(req, res) {
    console.log("GOING TO REMOVE!!!");
    console.log(req.query);

    item = req.query;
    Meetup.remove(item, function (err, results) {
        console.log("done");
        console.log(err);
        console.log(results);
    });
}
```

When I run my code and if I delete an already loaded item in the list, it is removed from Mongodb just fine. But if I add an item to the list and I **do not refresh** the page, it results in an error at my server that appears as

```
    GOING TO REMOVE!!!
    { '$resolved': 'true',
      __v: '0',
      _id: '54ec04e70398fab504085178',
      name: 'j' }
    done
    { [MongoError: unknown top level operator: $resolved]
      name: 'MongoError',
      code: 2,
      err: 'unknown top level operator: $resolved' }
    null
```

I if I refresh the page, the it gets deleted fine. But if I added the entry, angular seems to be adding a new variable $resolved. Why is that happening?

Also another question, What is the proper way to call delete? I call it now but I am not able to put a callback. I want a callback which returns and then I shift the list of items. I tried adding a callback but the code never reaches it.
ie I tried the following

```
        /*
        Meetup.delete(item, function () {
                console.log("In callback!!");
                console.log(returnValue);
                console.log(responseHeaders);
                $scope.meetups.splice(item);
            });
        */
        /*Meetup.delete(item, 
            function (returnValue, responseHeaders) {
                console.log("In callback!!");
                console.log(returnValue);
                console.log(responseHeaders);
                $scope.meetups.splice(item);
            },
            function (httpResponse){
                // error handling here
                console.log("Need to handle errors");
            });
        */
```

I am very new to node and am confused. Any help is very, very appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it possible to call `item.delete` instead of `Meetup.delete(item)`. You can call same methods on model instance. It prevent sending angular properties to server.

But better to make a rest API with delete method

DELETE /meetups/:id

and send just a _id

```
Meetup.remove({id: item._id});
```